# Solution existence of general multivariable quadratic equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

Consider the variables $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and the known coefficients $\mathbf{A}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \mathbf{A}^T = \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{b}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ and $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots, n$. They satisfy an $n$-equation system given by:
$$
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}_i \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}_i^T \mathbf{x} + c_i = 0, \quad i=1, 2,\cdots,n.
$$

**Question**: Could someone please give me some hints about the existence of a solution for this particular equation system? This question is extended from the topic discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648360/solving-general-multivariable-quadratic-equations).

**Constraints**: In my application, each $\mathbf{A}_i$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix with rank at most $3$ and ($n > 3$). Also, $\mathbf{b}_i$ is in column space of $\mathbf{A}_i$ (, or row space of $\mathbf{A}_i$ since $\mathbf{A}_i$ is symmetric). However, I would like to know what general constraints should be added to ensure the existence of a solution.

**Initial thoughts**: To guarantee the existence of a solution for this system, one should guarantee the solution existence for each equation. To determine this, we can quickly check the definiteness of $\mathbf{A}_i$ and examine the minimum or maximum of each LHS. The process for checking this is explained in detail in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665064/existence-of-real-roots-for-vector-quadratic-equations). However, this is not sufficient to determine the existence of a solution for the entire system, as the solution for the system requires the intersection of all solutions of each equation.

**Related post**: I could only locate [one closely related post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256365/solving-a-vector-of-quadratic-equations/256368#256368) on MathOverflow. However, the answer only supports $\mathbf{B}=[\mathbf{b}_1^T, \mathbf{b}_1^T,\cdots, \mathbf{b}_n^T]$ should be nonsingular M-matrix. In my application, $\mathbf{B}$ does not have such constraints but sometimes could have a solution via the Newton method.

Comment: I think the precise algebraic conditions for existence of a real solution are going to be very complicated, even in what seem like quite simple cases, like $n=3$.  I suspect that you'll need to use numerical methods to search for solutions.